# ng-selected required validation not working with checkbox

Tags: angularjs-directive

```
<label>Mark All Present:</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkall" ng-model="checkall">
<select name="status{{$index}}" ng-model="attendance_data[$index].status" required>
    <option value="">Select Status</option>
    <option value="Present" data-ng-selected="checkall">Present</option>
    <option value="Late">Late</option>
    <option value="Absent">Absent</option>
</select>
<span ng-show="submitted && attendance_form.status{{$index}}.$error.required">is Required</span>
```

On click on checkbox value selected as present,
but at the time of submission it shows is Required.
If i selected value with mouse on by one its working.

Answer (score 0):

Quick look at the ngSelected documentation: `Note: ngSelected does not interact with the select and ngModel directives, it only sets the selected attribute on the element. If you are using ngModel on the select, you should not use ngSelected on the options, as ngModel will set the select value and selected options.`

You should update your checkbox to set the select model value appropriately on ngChange.

Comment: ```if checkall then set all attendance data = 'Present' else set back to blank``` or back to the original value, dealers choice.